# Active and deactivate button, Remove list angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want toggle active and deactivate class in the button. For example for ref [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Mobile-Friendly-jQuery-Tags-Input-Plugin-Taxonomy/), in this i have 5 button when i click first button removed last button , how can i remove click button? and How to implement toggle active and deactivate class?

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label >Add</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value="" #newTag (keyup.enter)="addTag(newTag.value)" (blur)="addTag(newTag.value); newTag.value='' "></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button (click)=addTag(newTag.value)>Add</button>
    <button *ngFor="let category of categories" ion-button >{{category}} <span (click)="delete()">X</span></button>
```

file.ts

```
@Input()
  newTag: any;
  categories = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
  addTag(newTag: string) {
    if (newTag) {
      this.categories.push(newTag);
    }
  }
  delete() {
    var index = this.categories.indexOf(this.newTag);
    this.categories.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I am not sure of ionic framework. I worked with angular2 but not Ionic 2

```
<ion-item *ngIf="!showButton">
  <ion-label>Add</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" value="" #newTag (keyup.enter)="addTag(newTag.value)" (blur)="addTag(newTag.value); newTag.value='' "></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<button (click)="removeButton()">Add</button>
<button *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index;" ion-button>{{category}} <span (click)="delete(i)">X</span></button>


@Input()
newTag: any;
showButton: boolean = true;
categories = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];

removeButton() : void {
  this.showButton = false;
}

addTag(newTag: string) {
  if (newTag) {
    this.categories.push(newTag);
  }
}

delete(index) {
  this.categories.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**Using state for class**

Define the boolean variable

`stateOfButton: boolean = false;`

On your HTMLbutton

`<button [class.active="stateOfButton"] (click)="changeState()">Add</button>`

Style it as much as you want

`.active { background: red }`

On your Component

```
changeState(): void {
    this.stateOfButton = !this.stateOfButton;
}
```

Hope it works with you. Cheers!

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Mobile-Friendly-jQuery-Tags-Input-Plugin-Taxonomy/ i expert like this when click on button Active,and when i click this  <span (click)="delete()">X</span> current list delete list. not hide and show the input box

Comment: Use index to splice.

Comment: Thank you..  any idea about toggle Active and deactivate button

Comment: You need to create state. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: when i click button all button change color,  how can i change click button only?

Comment: Put [class.active] to the button you want to toggle. Not to all button.

Comment: i'm using ngfor list <button *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index;"> i need active tag name it customer option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128247/discussion-between-sridharan-and-wwwedevelop).